# Adding dummy 0-valued observations to dataset when performing min-max scaling

Tags: regression, normalization, feature-scaling

I'm using min-max scaling on a dataset on which I'm training a regression model. I have an independent variable $a$ whose values in the training set range from, say $1000$ to $10000$ but in general, could go down to $0$. I want to normalize this to the range $[0,1]$. However, I'm expecting that at prediction time, I might encounter a value of $a$ that is $<1000$. Then $a$ scaled using the training scaling schema would become negative which would also switch the signs of the prediction.

One solution I thought of is to add a dummy observation to the training set that would have value 0 for the variable that is being scaled and 0 for the target variables (those are theoretical extremes for both variables and are consistent with theoretical relationship). Can this hurt the model in some way?

Comment: Do you have a theoretical minimum and maximum?

Comment: The theoretical minimum is 0, no theoretical max . So should I just use 0 as min when scaling?

Comment: If you don't have limits on both sides then you cannot perform min-max scaling. Have you considered another type of normalization, such as standardization?

Comment: If I do this analysis, just $a_{new} = a_{old}/1000$.